# "I have multi-lingual ability" or "I'm a multi-lingual",how to say it?

Tags: translation

I'm filling in my CV in Japanese.

As the title mentioned, I've got some troubles how to give it a word into Japanese. "多言語話者【たげんごわしゃ】" or "優れた【すぐれた】言語能力【げんごのうりょく】" is what I've got so far.

Can someone help me describe it into a short paragraph? As for my case, I can speak five languages such as **Mandarin** (*15-year learning so far*) , **Cantonese** ( *mother tongue* ), **Malaysia** (*mother tongue*),  **Japanese** (*1.5-year learning so far*), **English** (*daily conversation*). And I wanna tell the interviewer that this is the most confident part of my CV.

I'll be very grateful for any help. Thank you.

Comment: You can have 優れた言語能力 even if you only speak one language.

Comment: Having filled out many a CV since coming to Jpn and being multilingual myself, it's usually best to state which languages and your ability in each instead of using "multilingual"/"bilingual". Multilingual and bilingual are fairly vague, for all they know the other languages could be ancient Latin and Klingon.

Answer (score 1):

Using Elimination method,　I think polyglot(ポリグロット） does not work. Other than that, I think it depends on the industry which you want to apply for. "多言語話者"　or "優れた言語能力" sound safe to me in CV. "マルチリンガル" might work if "バイリンガル" would work in the industry.

I am not working at human resource department. So, it's my pure speculation. Maybe some people only see the score of proficiency test of the language.

It might not be common in CV, they sometimes also say being fluent in multiple languages 多言語に堪能{たんのう}/流暢{りゅうちょう}.